# gcc options for exact casting from char*

Tags: c, gcc

I have checked many type-casting questions here but I couldn't find any to solve my problems.

I have a set of classes working interchangingly according to the case where they operate. I cant give full code, but I will shortly explain problematic points. They used to work until CodeBlocks corrupted and emptied all targets in project. After I added the same files, it compiled but never worked regularly. Then I debugged and noticed that gcc cant align data regularly at compile time. Which options can resolve it?

I am giving lines explaining each problem;

```
 char* buf; // assumed allocated
 int   num = 0;

 1 -   *(int*)buf = num; // I expect four bytes of zero but it writes 1 byte

 2 -  *(int*)buf ++ = num; // I expect buf to be incremented by 4 but it is buf+1

 3 -   *((int*)buf) ++ = num; // cant compile (never compiled with gcc)

 4 -   num = *buf ++; // I expect buf to be +1, but it increments buf by 4 bytes

 5 -   *(word)buf ++ = (word)0; // I expect 2 bytes 0, writes only 1 byte 0
```

What options may have gone away with corruption? 3 Never compiled, others used to compile and work regularly.

Comment: *After I added the same files, it compiled but never worked regularly.* -- So you relied on unknown settings to make this code "work"?  For things like this, you're supposed to know what the settings are for the compiler, not rely on a "lucky setting" or unknown setting.

Comment: `*(int*)buf++` is very different of `*((int*)buf)++`, I can't believe this compile on any true c compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this one is uncontested:

```
char* buf; // assumed allocated
int   num = 0;
```

Now, the first problem is here

```
*(int*)buf = num; // I expect four bytes of zero but it writes 1 byte
```

The cast `char *` -> `int *` has undefined behaviour if the pointer is not suitably aligned; furthermore in case of general pointer conversions, it would break strict aliasing rules.

```
*(int*)buf ++ = num; // I expect buf to be incremented by 4 but it is buf+1
```

Precedence, `++` increment *precedes* the cast. Additionally, if case **1** didn't have undefined behaviour, this most probably would, as you get an unaligned pointer that is then converted to a pointer to int.

```
*((int*)buf) ++ = num; // cant compile (never compiled with gcc)
```

This is not related to casts at all. The problem is that the left-hand construct casts the pointer as pointer to `int`, generating a value expression of type `int *`. This cannot be incremented, because it is not a variable; it is as meaningless as

```
5++;
```

As what it would mean to increment 5 by one and store the resulting value into 5?

```
num = *buf ++; // I expect buf to be +1, but it increments buf by 4 bytes
```

Well, this is just **blatantly false**. Remember that postfix operator increments *after*.

```
*(word)buf ++ = (word)0; // I expect 2 bytes 0, writes only 1 byte 0
```

This again is the same as case 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
*(int*)buf = num; // I expect four bytes of zero but it writes 1 byte
```

This will write `sizeof(int)` bytes to your buffer. What evidence do you have for "it writes 1 byte"?

---

```
*(int*)buf ++ = num; // I expect buf to be incremented by 4 but it is buf+1
```

`++` has [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than a (C-style) cast.  So after writing `sizeof(int)` bytes like the previous statement, this one will increment `buf` to point at the very next `char` in the buffer.  Your observed behavior sounds correct.

---

```
*((int*)buf) ++ = num; // cant compile (never compiled with gcc)
```

The cast expression `(int*)buf` creates a new temporary pointer which was converted from the value of `buf`.  It is not a name for the variable `buf`, and you can't modify it just like you can't do `x + y = z;`.  It sounds like you want:

```
*(int*)buf = num;
buf += sizeof(int);
```

---

```
num = *buf ++; // I expect buf to be +1, but it increments buf by 4 bytes
```

This will get the single `char` which `buf` points at, convert it to an `int` and store it in `num`, and then increment `buf` to point at the next `char` in the buffer.  What evidence do you have that "it increments `buf` by 4"?

---

```
*(word)buf ++ = (word)0; // I expect 2 bytes 0, writes only 1 byte 0
```

What is `word`? If it's a number type, this doesn't make any sense and shouldn't compile: you can't dereference a number expression `(word)buf++`.

If it's a pointer type, first please don't use typedefs that hide pointers!  And note again that since `++` has higher precedence than a cast, this will increment `buf` by one `char` after doing whatever `*(word)buf = (word)0;` would do.

Comment: aschepler, you always say "What evidence you have ...". I have evidence in currently test program. I debug it and check values. I am not a new programmer.and the lines I've added are working lines (except  *(int*)buf = num. It is given on 2 lines to describe two problems on 1 line. Another comment wonders if there is any compiler to compile *((int*)buf) ++ =num; borland compiler do it.

Comment: @İlhanÇELİK Well, that kind of extreme compiler bug doesn't really happen.  99.9% of the time somebody complains of this sort of thing on SO, it turns out the source they were looking at wasn't the source used to build the program, or they misunderstood some debugger information, or the debugger was just plain wrong.  I don't trust IDEs or debuggers nearly as much as actual program output.  And there's not much value in finding a compiler that accepts `*((int*)buf)++ = num;`, since at that point you're not writing valid C or C++.

Comment: you are right with word sample, there is a spelling mistake there. *(word*)buf = (word)0 (I cant write stars here)  The problem is not on source code, I am sure. It was working yesterday and doesnt work after corruption. I think config files got damage and I am asking which option should I check to fix it.

Comment: Use backward single quote marks to format a phrase as code (and prevent `*` characters from being interpreted as an italic phrase). Compiler options would depend on what compiler you're using, which you haven't said. But no common compilers have any configuration at all which would cause exactly what you described.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning about compiler. My question has "gcc" tag and I thought gcc has same common options. I am using CodeBlocks 16.01 with default compiler (I think V4.92). I set up working environment long time ago and I didnt need anything related with options except debug/relase mode settings. I created templates and open prjects from templates. There had been no problems so far...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by going back to Borland C++ 5.02.

```
  3 -   *((int*)buf) ++ = num; // cant compile (never compiled with gcc)
```

is the main problem here. My working copy was adopted to gcc by changing that phrase into codes like

```
*(type*)buf = (type)num;
buf += sizeof(type);
```

I am posting a pair of working copy (about which some of you say never works) to  serialize a Node, having list of sub-nodes which may have other sublists of Nodes ... (gets and puts are not the ones you know, they are specific for me)

```
int    __fastcall HNode::send(char* buf)
{
    char* tmp = buf;
    if(this)
    {
        *((word*)tmp) ++ = *(word*)B; // first 16 bits (persistent info)
        tmp += HspKod::send(tmp);
        tmp += puts(tmp, str); // acn name
        tmp += alt->send(tmp); // node list (null writes (word)0 only
    } return tmp-buf;
}

int    __fastcall HNode::read(char* buf)
{
    char* tmp = buf;
    if(this)
    {
        *(word*)B = *((word*)tmp) ++; // persistent info bits
        tmp += HspKod::read(tmp);
        tmp += gets(tmp, str); // acn name
        int num = *((word*)tmp); // number of sub-nodes
        if(num && alt==0)
            alt = new HNods(this);
        tmp += alt->read(tmp);  // alt reads 2 bytes even if it is null
    } return tmp-buf;
}
```